# What is the sequence combinator in Chomp?

Tags: parsing, rust

I'm attempting to parse a subset of JSON that only contains a single, non-nested object with string only values that may contain escape sequences. E.g.

```
{
  "A KEY": "SOME VALUE",
  "Another key": "Escape sequences \n \r \\ \/ \f \t \u263A"
}
```

Using the [Chomp](https://crates.io/crates/chomp) parser combinator in Rust. I have it parsing this structure ignoring escape sequences but am having trouble working out how to handle the escape sequences. Looking at other quoted string parsers that use combinators such as:

- [Arc JSON parser](http://hacks.catdancer.ws/parser-combinator-approach-to-json.html)
- [PHP parser-combinator](https://github.com/Vektah/parser-combinator/blob/master/src/main/vektah/parser_combinator/parser/literal/StringLiteral.php#L22)
- [Paka](https://github.com/weidagang/paka-js/blob/master/paka.js#L239)

They each use a sequence combinator, what is the equivalent in `Chomp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chomp is based on Attoparsec and Parsec, so for parsing escaped strings I would use the [`scan`](http://m4rw3r.github.io/chomp/chomp/parsers/fn.scan.html) parser to obtain the slice between the `"` characters while keeping any escaped `"` characters.

The sequence combinator is just the [`ParseResult::bind`](http://m4rw3r.github.io/chomp/chomp/struct.ParseResult.html#method.bind) method, used to chain the match of the `"` character and the escaped string itself so that it will be able to parse `"foo\\"bar"` and not just `foo\\"bar`. You get this for free when you use the [`parse!`](http://m4rw3r.github.io/chomp/chomp/macro.parse!.html) macro, each `;` is implicitly converted into a `bind` call to chain the parsers together.

The linked parsers use a [`many`](http://m4rw3r.github.io/chomp/chomp/combinators/fn.many.html) and [`or`](http://m4rw3r.github.io/chomp/chomp/combinators/fn.or.html) combinator and allocate a vector for the resulting characters. Paka does not seem to do any transformation on the resulting array, and PHP is using a regex with a callback to unescape the string.

This is code translated from [Attoparsec's Aeson benchmark](https://github.com/bos/attoparsec/blob/4f137347be02106765f6897059b88219c79bb86c/benchmarks/Aeson.hs#L210) for parsing a JSON-string while not unescaping any escaped characters.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate chomp;

use chomp::*;
use chomp::buffer::IntoStream;
use chomp::buffer::Stream;

pub fn json_string(i: Input<u8>) -> U8Result<&[u8]> {
    parse!{i;
                          token(b'"');
        let escaped_str = scan(false, |s, c| if s { Some(false) }
                                             else if c == b'"' { None }
                                             else { Some(c == b'\\') });
                          token(b'"');

        ret escaped_str
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_it() {
    let r = "\"foo\\\"bar\\tbaz\"".as_bytes().into_stream().parse(json_string);

    assert_eq!(r, Ok(&b"foo\\\"bar\\tbaz"[..]));
}
```

The parser above is not equivalent, it yields a slice of `u8` borrowed from the source buffer/slice. If you want an owned `Vec` of the data you should preferably use [`[T]::to_vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec) or [`String::from_utf8`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) instead of building a parser using `many` and `or` since it will not be as fast as `scan` and the result is the same.

If you want to parse UTF-8 and escape-sequences you can filter the resulting slice and then calling `String::from_utf8` on the `Vec` (Rust strings are UTF-8, to use a string containing invalid UTF-8 can result in undefined behaviour). If performance is an issue you should build that into the parser most likely.

Comment: Can't get much more of an authoritative answer than from the author! A bit off-topic, but I'm happy that you chose to use an iterator for `many` / `many1` — without doing actual performance numbers, it makes me think that it will be nicely performant. Keep up the great work!

Comment: @Shepmaster Currently they do not pre-allocate (ie. implement [`Iterator::size_hint`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.size_hint), I have [an issue](https://github.com/m4rw3r/chomp/issues/24) for it which will improve performance since it will hopefully not reallocate as much.The main reason for `FromIterator` in the combinators is that I did not want to limit users to populating `Vec`s with them.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://m4rw3r.github.io/chomp/chomp/index.html) states (emphasis mine):

> Using parsers is almost entirely done using the `parse!` macro, which enables us to do three distinct things:
>
> - **Sequence parsers over the remaining input**
> - Store intermediate results into datatypes
> - Return a datatype at the end, which may be the result of any arbitrary computation over the intermediate results.

It then provides this example of parsing a sequence of two numbers followed by a constant string:

```
fn f(i: Input<u8>) -> U8Result<(u8, u8, u8)> {
    parse!{i;
        let a = digit();
        let b = digit();
                string(b"missiles");
        ret (a, b, a + b)
    }
}

fn digit(i: Input<u8>) -> U8Result<u8> {
    satisfy(i, |c| b'0' <= c && c <= b'9').map(|c| c - b'0')
}
```

There is also [`ParseResult::bind`](http://m4rw3r.github.io/chomp/chomp/struct.ParseResult.html#method.bind) and [`ParseResult::then`](http://m4rw3r.github.io/chomp/chomp/struct.ParseResult.html#method.then) which are documented to sequentially compose a result with a second action.

---

Because I'm always interested in parsing, I went ahead and played with it a bit to see how it would look. I'm not happy with the deep indenting that would happen with the nested `or` calls, but there's probably something better that can be done. This is just one possible solution:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate chomp;

use chomp::*;
use chomp::ascii::is_alpha;
use chomp::buffer::{Source, Stream, ParseError};

use std::str;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum StringPart<'a> {
    String(&'a [u8]),
    Newline,
    Slash,
}

impl<'a> StringPart<'a> {
    fn from_bytes(s: &[u8]) -> StringPart {
        match s {
            br#"\\"# => StringPart::Slash,
            br#"\n"# => StringPart::Newline,
            s => StringPart::String(s),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> FromIterator<StringPart<'a>> for String {
    fn from_iter<I>(iterator: I) -> Self
        where I: IntoIterator<Item = StringPart<'a>>
    {
        let mut s = String::new();
        for part in iterator {
            match part {
                StringPart::String(p) => s.push_str(str::from_utf8(p).unwrap()),
                StringPart::Newline => s.push('\n'),
                StringPart::Slash => s.push('\\'),
            }
        }
        s
    }
}

fn json_string_part(i: Input<u8>) -> U8Result<StringPart> {
    or(i,
       |i| parse!{i; take_while1(is_alpha)},
       |i| or(i,
              |i| parse!{i; string(br"\\")},
              |i| parse!{i; string(br"\n")}),
    ).map(StringPart::from_bytes)
}

fn json_string(i: Input<u8>) -> U8Result<String> {
    many1(i, json_string_part)
}

fn main() {
    let input = br#"\\stuff\n"#;

    let mut i = Source::new(input as &[u8]);

    println!("Input has {} bytes", input.len());

    loop {
        match i.parse(json_string) {
            Ok(x)                       => {
                println!("Result has {} bytes", x.len());
                println!("{:?}", x);
            },
            Err(ParseError::Retry)      => {}, // Needed to refill buffer when necessary
            Err(ParseError::EndOfInput) => break,
            Err(e)                      => { panic!("{:?}", e); }
        }
    }
}
```